# best way to call a classmethod on a generic type parameter's class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine the following code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, Optional, Self, Type, TypeVar, get_args

class EntityBase(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def factory(cls) -> Self:
        pass
    
class EntityA(EntityBase):
    @classmethod    
    def factory(cls) -> Self:
        return cls()

class EntityB(EntityBase):
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls) -> Self:
        return cls()

T = TypeVar("T", bound=EntityBase)

class EntityProcessorBase(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def get_all(self) -> Optional[EntityBase]:
        # we pass data from external sources to the factory but is omitted for brevity
        return get_args(self.__class__.__orig_bases__[0])[0].factory() # type: ignore

class EntityAProcessor(EntityProcessorBase[EntityA]):
    pass

class EntityBProcessor(EntityProcessorBase[EntityB]):
    pass 

print(EntityAProcessor().get_all())
print(EntityBProcessor().get_all())
```

Relying on `__orig_bases__` feels like relying on an implementation detail (it debuted in [PEP-560](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/)) but I don't have a better idea.

In the upcoming [PEP-695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) it is proposed to have `__type_params__` available at runtime, with the PEP saying:

> The tuple contains TypeVar, ParamSpec, and TypeVarTuple instances.

Not sure what I'd do with the TypeVar to get to `Type[T]` - because of `T`'s bound to EntityBase, Type[T] would be guaranteed to have the factory classmethod.

Based on previous stackoverflow discussion this could be rewritten to achieve the same functionality in a couple of ways, but I'd like to use `T` which is already there without repetition.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this than the above implementation?

Comment: Aside from the awkward documentation status of `__orig_bases__`, your code also has problems with grandchild classes or multiple inheritance. You'd need to search the MRO for the right `__orig_bases__` and the right element of that `__orig_bases__` to handle that properly.

Comment: The *pythonic* way would be, IMO, would be to simply have your `class EnttityProcessor(Generic[T])` accept as an argument the entity class, e.g. `def __init__(self, entity_class: type[T])`...  and just use it directly. Then you don't create subclasses, you just create instances of your generic `EntitiyProcessor`, e.g. `a_processor = EntityProcessor(entity_type=EntityA)` and then your `get_all` is just `return self.entity_type.factory()`

Comment: What exactly is `get_all` supposed to *do*, that you think it relies on `__orig_bases__`? (For that matter, why is `get_all` an instance method instead of a class method, and why is `T` never referenced anywhere inside the definition of `EntityProcessor`?)

Comment: @chepner: It's accessing the type parameter at runtime. `T` would be useless for that - at runtime, it's still just the type variable `T`, not whatever `T` was supposed to be bound to.

Comment: @chepner: we need the class to be Generic in order to have access to the generic type parameters which are actually used to typecheck that you are processing the right type. what get_all does is in the comment: it fetches external data to create the objects, but for brevity, I've omitted those parts. they are not relevant to the type discussion.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: that's what you'd do in Java, and I find that a not so good solution. the type is available already as the generic type parameter.

Comment: @Zoltán: There's no actual guarantee the type parameter is available at runtime, even in Python. For one thing, `EntityProcessorBase` isn't actually abstract - it has no abstract methods. For another, a subclass could leave out the type parameter, or a subclass could be generic, in which case code that instantiates the subclass might infer the type parameter instead of providing it at runtime.

Comment: In my example, you wouldn't use a generic type parameter, so there wouldn't be any unnecessary repetition, but static type checkers would still infer it properly and it would be just as type safe.